# Notepad++ macro problem: inserting extra characters

Tags: notepad++, macros

I sometimes run into a problem when playing back Notepad++ macros in that it inserts extra characters between all the letters, e.g. ”. Anyone else seeing this?

Comment: Do you have an example of a macro that does this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug, that has been fixed, as you can see here "[Keyboard Macro's inserting text in the wrong place](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/304)"

A new release of notepad++ should incorporate this fix. Perhaps Notepad++ release 6.8.4

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I do see this error, I have always used Textpad for macro just for this purpose.

I have list of numbers that I wanted to convert into a string array.

ex.

12345
45678

to

"12345",
"45678"

before you create a macro. Paste a list of numbers on an new file, click start recording
put a " (quote), press end key and then put another quote followed by comma, down arrow and then
ctrl-left arrow. stop the macro. now when you play it, it puts the following stuff
"12345", actually the squared unknown char is DC2, I have no idea what it is.